# How to line up rounded corners with a border in a separate element?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve rounded corner borders in a document with three divs. The top div will contain the top corner, the middle div a straight section, and the third the bottom corner. I'm applying `border-top-left-radius` and `border-bottom-left-radius` to the first and third divs respectively.

You can see what this looks like here: https://codepen.io/thomasjm/pen/zYNgzXv

The trouble is, in Chrome there's some anti-aliasing issue (I think) that causes it to look jagged where the divs meet. (You may need to zoom the browser in to see it clearly.)

[image: jagged edge]

I've noticed I can make it look okay by increasing the width of the corner pieces slightly, to `4.1px` or so instead of `4px`. But I'm hoping to find a real solution.

EDIT: I'm using Chrome 90.0.4430.72 on Ubuntu 20.04.2.

EDIT 2: it looks strange in a totally different way on Firefox, where there seems to be some antialiasing near the top and bottom only:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I am not seeing that on my version of Chrome...

Comment: Interesting, just edited the post to add browser version and OS.

Comment: Can't spot it. Mac Chrome Version 90.0.4430.93, and Mac Firefox 88.0.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried a Mac and I can confirm it doesn't appear there--only on my Linux machine. I haven't tried Windows.

Comment: On Windows I was able to reproduce it with Chrome, and also with a slightly different appearance on Edge.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix it. It seems to only happen when an alpha channel is present in the color. So if I change the color from `rgb(66, 133, 244, 0.5)` to `rgb(66, 133, 244)`, the boundary between the divs becomes perfectly smooth.